# Current date in ftl template

Tags: java, date, freemarker

Is it possible to print current date in specified format (`Y-m-d H:i:s`) in ftl (FreeMarker) ?
I want to avoid passing date from controller to view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freemarker is a templating library, there isn't a today variable, you should consider passing a `new Date()` Java Object to the template, and format it. Consider to create a wrapper class for this, to generate the new Date() exactly at the time it is called.

Answer (score 2):

Tying up to the above answer: Once you place date object into your model you do this:

```
 date?string("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

[see freemarker doc](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_string_date)